# How do I implement a blend/wpf attached behavior that refrences another control as a property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expression-blend, attachedbehaviors

I'm trying to implement a behavior that works on an object, but is affected by a second object.

As an example, it will change the appearance of the framework element based on the distance of another framework element.

I know just enough about attached behaviors to be dangerous, and I would define my class like this :

```
 public class ChangeWithDistance : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
```

And somewhere in the behavior I would need a dependency property that would point at the name(?) of the other control.

What is the class I should make my dependency property so that I can have this behavior point to another control?

Would I specify the propdp as a string that represents the name of the other control?

Or is there another class I should use that signifies the tag associated with a control (you know, that x:Name business..)

Or should the propdp be pointing at a framework element like this?

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OtherControl =     
          DependencyProperty.Register("OtherControl", typeof(FrameworkElement)
```

Or do I do something with binding?

Is there a best practice of how to point a behavior or really anything that has a dependency property at another control?

Is there a way to make it show up so a user using blend can select the other control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having good luck declaring my dependency property as such :

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty OtherObjectProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("OtherObject", typeof (FrameworkElement), typeof (MyBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata());
```

And then in the XAML binding it to the other object I am interested like this :

```
  <Rectangle ....>
       <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
             <Controls:MyBehavior OtherObject="{Binding ElementName=TheOtherElementNameIWantToReference}" />
       </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
  </Rectangle>
```

Comment: ChangeWithDistance : Behavior<FrameworkElement> does not implement dependencyObject hence you get a XAML error "A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject."

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of questions in one.  Read up on attached properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx

The short answer is that you need to use the `RegisterAttached` method, rather than `Register`.

Comment: I understand attached properties (I think.)  I don't have a problem with attaching a property to object A, my problem is I want to specify in XAML that attached property (to A) also knows about object B.  By name?  By string?  By passing in a binding?

Thus, my question is simply "How do you reference another object using properties"

Comment: @JeremyWhite I suspect that you misunderstand attached properties.  An attached property is specifically for cases where one object needs to know about the other.  For example, when you put a control into a `Grid`, the there is an attached `Grid.Row` property (and `Grid.Column`).  These properties are not available in XAML if the control is not contained in a Grid.  This seems to be analogous to your case; the behavior of the control (first object) is affected by the grid (second object).

Comment: @JeremyWhite also note that the first several pages here use attached properties (and `RegisterAttached`): https://www.google.com/q=attached+behavior  The "attached" in attached property means, that the type *defining* the attached property (Grid, for example) *attaches* the property to an object of a different type (TextBlock, for example).  Then you don't have to worry about element names; the signatures of the attached property getter and setter include a parameter that points to the object that's using the attached property.

Comment: Yes, I know how to use the AssociatedObject.

What I need is a reference/binding to a *third* object, not just the main object and the attached.